# Sci-Fi Book: Human colonization alongside ants

Tags: story-identification

There is an old book series out there that may feature ants or refer to ants. My father read them many years ago and is interested in finding them again. I am afraid I do not have a lot to go on regarding information, but I have been randomly typing into Google and it has got me nowhere. I know that my father is a fan of Stephen King, but I have no idea what the series is called. I know it has an unusual name, and there may be a fair few books in this old series. Hopefully someone will recognize my ramblings and be able to help me.

**Edit from comments:** I know I am being of little help here. I remember from the conversation about it that it was an old book series and I think in the sci-fi genre. There were quite a few books in the series and perhaps something to do with human colonization alongside ants? It wasn't something I read it was my father and he is interested in reading them again but due to bad health he has very little memory of details about them.
I feel I would recognize the title if it is mentioned.

As far as I can tell the series is not 'empire of the ants'.

Comment: Do you have any plot elements, genre data, character names, or anything else? 'Features or refers to ants' is a little too vague; you mention Mr. King -- is it horror?  Thriller?  SciFi?  Any data you can provide may help.

Comment: I know I am being of little help here. I remember from the conversation about it that it was an old book series and I think in the sci fi genre. There were quite a few books in the series and perhaps something to do with human colonization along side ants? It wasn't something I read it was my father and he is interested in reading them again but due to bad health he has very little memory of details about them.

Comment: @elektra77 I took the liberty of editing those details into your question; if you remember anything else, please edit them in as well. Comments can be deleted for no reason, and we wouldn't want to lose some crucial piece of info because of it

Comment: I think the question is... if we find the right answer, will you know? I'm assuming that you can mention the answers to your father and he can give that answer? I added in mention that it is your father looking for it. That may help in establishing a time period.

Comment: I feel I would know yes as he once told me the name of the series but he is now not sure of it. So with a prompt I would remember.

Comment: Possibly Phylogenesis, or another of Alan Dean Foster's "Humanx" novels.  The Thranx aren't exactly ants, but they're insectoid - Wikipedia says "resembling large praying mantises".

Answer (score 4):

Evolved, intelligent hive-mind ants of the future play an important role in the classic novel [City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_%28novel%29) by Clifford Simak.  It's not a series as such, but is a fix-up novel, created from a series of short stories and novellas.

> Each successive tale tells of further breakdown of urban society. As
>   mankind abandons the cities, each family becomes increasingly
>   isolated. Bruce Webster surgically provides dogs with a means of
>   speech and better vision. The breakdown of civilization allows
>   wandering mutant geniuses to grow up unrestrained by conventional
>   mores. ***A mutant called Joe invents a way for ants to stay active year
>   round in Wisconsin, so that they need not start over every spring.
>   Eventually the ants form an industrial society in their hill. The
>   amoral Joe, tiring of the game, kicks over the anthill. The ants
>   ignore this setback and build bigger and more industrialized colonies.***

(italics mine)

Answer (score 2):

Check out "empire of the ants" 1991. It's a parallel story set in the 21st century about humans in Paris and an ant colony in a park. We deal with mysterious happenings to both ants and humans along with secret societies who guard "the truth".

It's a trilogy which makes me believe this may be a match.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd books are in french so this cannot be the series.

Answer (score 2):

It's a stretch, but maybe [Serpent's Reach by C.J.Cherryh?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent%27s_Reach)

You don't say if you mean normal-sized ants, when I read your description I assumed you meant some sort of giant, human-sized ants.

Anyway, Serpent's Reach has a human colony living alongside a human-sized insect lifeform with hive minds, drones, queens, workers, etc.

There aren't, as far as I know, multiple books about this particular colony.  But it's part of Cherryh's Alliance-Union universe, for which there are certainly "quite a few" books.

Answer (score 2):

Thos is a long shot, but I wonder if your father is (mis) remembering the Thranx from [Alan Dean Foster's Commonwealth books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanx_Commonwealth).

I've always mentally pictured the Thranx as more like a preying mantis than an ant, but I guess they could be interpreted as looking a bit like giant ants. The books aren't formally a series, more lots of related books set in the same universe, but they could be viewed as a series and they are vaguely related to colonisation because they describe the expansion of the human race into the galaxy.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be "The Radio Man" series by Ralph Milne Farley (real name Roger Sherman Hoar)? The first volume was published in 1925. The series includes "The Radio Man", "The Radio Beasts", "The Radio Planet", "The Radio Menace", and "The Radio Mind". This is an adventure series about a man's travel to another planet, where humans with a natural radio communication sense coexist with giant, sometimes intelligent, insects.
This blurb is from Amazon:
When Myles Cabot accidentally transmitted himself to the planet Venus, he found himself naked and bewildered on a mystery world where every unguarded minute might mean a horrible death. Man-eating plants, tiger-sized spiders, and dictatorial ant-men kept Myles on the run until he discovered the secret of the land—that humanity was a slave-race and that the monster ants were the real rulers of the world! But Cabot was resourceful, and when his new found love, the Kewpie-doll princess Lilla, called for help, the ant-men learned what an angry Earthman can do. THE RADIO MAN is a science-fiction adventure packed with the excitement of an Edgar Rice Burroughs, and the science-vision of an H. G. Wells. You won’t be able to put it down once you start it.

[image]